# How to set the fontsize programmatically to fit numberOflines value in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I have two UILabels named headingLabel and descriptionLabel whose number of lines is 3 and 5 respectively. Now I want the font-size of the text to change and fit into the numberOfLines where the text  varies based on some networking json data received.

[image: image for text in iphone5s]           [image: image for text in iphoneX]

```
 here is my code

    let headingLabel : UILabel = {
        let hl = UILabel()
        hl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hl.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor"

        hl.textColor = .black
        hl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        hl.numberOfLines = 3;
        hl.sizeToFit()
        hl.clipsToBounds = true
        hl.font = hl.font.withSize(20)

        return hl
    }()

    let descriptionLabel : UILabel = {
        let dl = UILabel()
        dl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dl.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet Lorem ipsum dolor"
        dl.textColor = .black
        dl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        dl.numberOfLines = 5
        dl.font = dl.font.withSize(18)
        dl.sizeToFit()
        dl.clipsToBounds = true
        dl.alpha = 0.8
        return dl
    }()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Autoshrink to adjust text into label frame.

#### Authoshrink with Minimum Font Size

[image]

#### Authoshrink with Minimum Font Scale

[image]

#### Apple document about UILabel - [Autoshrink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel?changes=_2)

*Determines whether the label adjusts the appearance of the text before resorting to truncation. Choose Minimum Font Scale and enter a value to allow the label to reduce the font size to fit the text. Enable Tighten Letter Spacing to allow the label to reduce intercharacter spacing. Access these values at runtime with the minimumScaleFactor and allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation properties, respectively.*

Comment: I would just add: note that the Line Break : Truncate Tail setting is important for this to work. Mere Word Wrap line breaking will not behave this way. Also note that there is _no guarantee_ that the text will shrink enough for it all to fit (as indeed in the last example of your screen shot, it does not fit: it is truncated instead).

Comment: @matt - You are welcomed to improve, quality of this answer. Please add your input by editing this answer. About last example, I've just shown a way, how an OP can solve her problem. She can reduce font scale to fit text into frame, according to text size visibility requirement.

Comment: Well, let's let the comment stand as a comment, then. I really don't want to detract from your answer in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Please give:

```
dl.numberOfLines =  0
```

[image]

Comment: if I give numberOfLines = 0 the text overflows out of the rectangular UIView Box. I want the text to be within the box

Comment: Im thinking of UITextView as an alternative if nothing works.If you have any solution using textview please share it

Comment: Please check in Screenshot LinebreakMode = TruncateTail

Comment: what? I didnt get you

Comment: linebreakmode is truncatetail

Comment: I tried it the minimumScaleFacter is set to 0.5 but the text is not shrinking in size

Comment: minimum scale factor is not need

Comment: Then how  do you change the fontsize dynamically when the screen size changes and the UIView Box has different size

Comment: have u used XIB or storyboard there are option vary for trait in you can set with Height/width varition based on requirements

Comment: No Ihavent used storyboard its created programmatically

Comment: I am trying to set the fontsize based on the current device .not the best way to do it but there seems to be no other option